# Resolving RVA's for Import and Export tables within a PE file

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am currently writing a PE parser/loader.
I have successfully loaded the PE file into memory using standard c file io, retrieved valid DOS and PE headers (the optional header) as well as gaining access to the PE's sections.
My next target is to gain access to the Export table to retrieve exported symbols.
To do this i have used the RVA stored in the optional headers data-dictionary array at index 0 (which i believe points to the export table) and added this address to the address of the PE file loaded into program memory, then casted this into a valid export table header. I am turning up NULL addresses and data when i do this. here is a small code snippet;

```
// RVA from optional headers data dictionaries array cast to Export directory type 
  IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY* ied(
  (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY*)((void*)
  ((unsigned char*)buffer + ioh->DataDirectory[0].VirtualAddress)));
```

Do i have to use memory mapped IO to do this properly? Am i calculating the address wrong? Information on PE RVA's seems sparse.
thanks in advance.

Comment: The set of articles pointed to in this SO answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307754/within-a-dll-how-is-the-function-table-structured/2307850#2307850

Answer (score 16):

I opened one my old project from the time as I like you examined the structure of import and export directories (`IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT`, `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT`, `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT` and `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT`). I can in short explain the part where you have a problem. I mean the part how to find out the pointer to for example `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` inside of PE.

First of all of cause it is possible to use Read/Write file operations to analyse a PE file, but it is much easier to use file mapping like following:

```
hSrcFile = CreateFile (pszSrcFilename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                       NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
hMapSrcFile = CreateFileMapping (hSrcFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
pSrcFile = (PBYTE) MapViewOfFile (hMapSrcFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
```

after we have the pointer `pSrcFile` which point to the PE file contain we can find another important places inside of PE:

```
pDosHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *)pSrcFile;
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 *pNtHdr = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 *)
    ((PBYTE)pDosHeader + pDosHeader->e_lfanew);
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *pFirstSectionHeader = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *)
    ((PBYTE)&pNtHdr->OptionalHeader +
     pNtHdr->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader);
```

Now we have all needed virtual address of any directory. For example,

```
pNtHdr->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress
```

is a virtual address of export directory. After that to convert the virtual address to the memory pointer, **we should find out the section of PE which has this virtual address inside**. To do this we can enumerate sections of PE and find an `i` greater or equal to `0` and less then `pNtHdr->FileHeader.NumberOfSection`s where

```
pFirstSectionHeader[i].VirtualAddress <= 
pNtHdr->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress
```

and at the same time

```
pNtHdr->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress
< pFirstSectionHeader[i].VirtualAddress + pFirstSectionHeader[i].Misc.VirtualSize
```

then you should search for export data in the section `pFirstSectionHeader[i]`:

```
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *pSectionHeader = &pFirstSectionHeader[i];
IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *pExportDirectory =
   (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *)((PBYTE)pbyFile + pSectionHeader->PointerToRawData +
    pOptionalHeader->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress -
    pSectionHeader->VirtualAddress);
```

The same procedure you should repeat to find `(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR *)` which corresponds to `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT` and `(IMAGE_BOUND_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR *)` which corresponds to `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT` to dump import information inclusive a binding information (if exist).

To dump information from `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT` (corresponds to `(ImgDelayDescr *)` defined in delayimp.h) you should use also information from the `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT` (corresponds to `(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32 *)`).

For more information about PE I recommend you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx

Comment: Just for clarification, can you say where `pbyFile` comes from?

Comment: @DebugErr: It's the same as `pSrcFile` used before. One don't need to read the whole EXE/DLL file in memory. One can just use memory mapping methods to access it.

Comment: I see, I'm writing this in C#, so I'm a bit lazy right now and just needed the address in the file (pSrcFile would just be 0 then for the calculation). I implemented your function, but except for the TimeDateStamp field, all my other ExportDataDirectory fields look horribly wrong :(

Comment: @DebugErr: Sorry, but I can't debug your code. I can only guess that you can have problems with 64-bit/32-bit. See my [another old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3430822/315935).

Comment: I didn't want you to :) I'll read over the MSDN article again, if I found a solution, I'll post what I did wrong.

Comment: @DebugErr: Do you tried [the code](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/PEInfo.c) which I referenced in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3430822/315935)? Does it produce the correct results for your test DLL/EXE? If it's so that you will need just to rewrite it using managed code.

Comment: Compared you code with mine, looks like the data I parsed out wasn't so wrong. However, your code also has problems with many exports, it prints several lines going like `29 [NONAME] (forwarded to ï Uï∞ §...)` (tried to parse `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll` of Win 8.1.1)

Comment: @DebugErr. I'm sure thet in 10 year the code will displays even more errors for the files compiled 10 years later. :-) I can you suggest to debug the code only. I personally do nothing in the direction since years...

Comment: I solved it in C#, it works flawlessy from the first tries. In case you're interested, this is the code: http://debugerr.vibeware.net/stackoverflow/ReadExportTables.cs

Answer (score 1):

There is macro defined to get first section

`PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER FisrtSection = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(NtHeaders)`

Answer (score 0):

Not all PE images will have an export directory table. You need to check the optional header's Windows-specific "NumberOfRvaAndSizes" field. If it is less than or equal to `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT` (0), then there is no export directory table (i.e. there is nothing valid located at `ioh->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT]`).

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273603/getting-ordinal-from-function-name-programatically) for an example.

Comment: For example, an EXE only have an import section or more, but doesn't having an export section. And you said "less than or equal to `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT`" even `NumberOfRvaAndSizes` is a DWORD.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the python code to print all import and export functions of pe file. You will get the nice idea of how to do that in C. In data directory we have to check if the export directory rva and size is '0' or not. if not '0' we can proceed. You can use tool 'CFF explorer' from Nt core website. this is very good tool which will show how the data maps into export directory and then you can parse it easily. Here is the [blog](https://aroundthemalware.wordpress.com/2022/02/06/parsing-pe-file-in-python-without-using-pefile-python-package/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31006342)