# IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY wrong values

Tags: c++, c, winapi, portable-executable

I'm having trouble with `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` values, whenever I'm calculating address of it, it gives me wrong values (like `Name`, `NumberOfNames`, `AddressOfNames`, etc..).
I'm calculating it by the following code.

```
IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *export_directory = (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY*)(nt_headers->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[0].VirtualAddress + (DWORD)dos_header);
```

Following in debugger, the address is right, there must be a `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY`, but why it gives me wrong results? Can't access any of the elements from it, because it says bad ptr..
Tried and works fine with `kernel32.dll`, but fails on `user32.dll` when extracting names from AddressOfNames.

Using Windows 8 x86.

Comment: VirtualAddress is only the *preferred* load address for a section.  It doesn't commonly actually load there, a DLL will be relocated if its preferred load address is already in use.  And it may be randomized by the ASLR feature.  Cast the return value of GetModuleHandle to void* to find the actual load address.

Comment: I'm not yet using relocations, I'm using ReadFile to buffer instead of GetModuleHandle.

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975639/resolving-rvas-for-import-and-export-tables-within-a-pe-file

Comment: Thanks, at first try I don't understood that answer, but then idk how but I understood it. I'm beginner in C/C++.

Comment: You need to subtract the actual location of the section on disk vs the section (when expanded) in ram.